# How to produce 500 Internal Server Error in PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I would like to produce a 500 Internal server error page with PHP, how could I do that?

Comment: Write a line of code that has an error in it.

Comment: You want to trigger a 500 error condition using PHP, or you want to have a PHP page come up when there is a 500 error?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/header

Comment: also, clarify what you are after: sending the header or creating the page

Comment: I'd just like to have a page where it is displyed, because I'd like to copy/ paste the message! And when I'm ready I'd liek to test it.

Comment: If you just want to test how your request would be handled when reaching a 500 page, you may want to give https://httpstat.us/ a try. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a bad .htaccess file (put some junk in it).

Comment: It would not actually be raised by PHP then, it would be by Apache.

Comment: It isn't clear what is he after.

Comment: The title of the question says “in PHP”.

Comment: Thank you man, it just worked :)

Comment: Could you also please let me know how to generate a 400 error?

Comment: HTTP 400: set the acceptable data size very low in httpd.conf (limitrequestfieldsize if i'm correct) and then send for example a huge cookie (30 kB)

Comment: @PeterKiss your answer might seem to work as intended but it does not reply the original question. the op asks how to trigger it from php. you are doing it with a really ugly hack from apache, which might not even work in some cases.

Comment: Wow, accepted answer with a negative rep. There's got to be a badge for that! :)

Comment: The HTTP500 error will not send by PHP no meather it is becouse of the PHP. HTTP500 will fired when no other suitable error messages are available and in most cases this is becouse misconfiguration and yes this will work always.

Comment: @PeterKiss it will not work always, if the server is not configured to use `access_files`, nothing will happen.

Comment: It's true but i'm sure we are talking about a development environment not a production one.

Comment: @PeterKiss and we are not sure whether the OP is working in a machine he totally controls or not. You are just guessing. Still, your answer is the least useful. It was just picked because of the inexperience of the OP and inability to formulate a clear question.

Comment: @ppeterka it could be a badge for catching the attention of a clueless OP with a poor answer.

Answer (score 19):

`header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");` before any output is... output.
With the output sent after this function you can then show a custom page explaining the error.

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    exit("I error because foo");
?>
```

You can read the [manual page of `header()` function](http://php.net/header) for more information.

If you want to make the default’s Apache page to display, there is no direct way to load it from PHP, but you can do a hack like this:

```
<?php
    if ($error)
        require("badfile.php");
?>
```

and in badfile.php:

```
<?php strpos) ?>
```

For example.

Another solution to try, you can throw an exception that nobody will catch.

```
<?php
    if ($error)
        throw new \Exception("Error because foo");
?>
```

Or copy and paste the original file used by Apache and print it after the error happens:

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    header('Content-Type: text/html');
    readfile('path/to/html/file.html');
    exit(1);
?>
```

Comment: Nice! Haven't thought of that... Deleted post of infinite recursion...

Comment: @ppeterka I got to read it and lold. Found it way too hardcore. :P

Comment: Lol, it just gave me the "I error because foo" message.... However I'd like to have the default Internal Error message.

Comment: @user1406071 Probably by “default” error message you mean the one of Apache. There is no real way to directly summon it form PHP. But if you want to hack it. Just include a PHP file with syntax error when the error should happen.

Comment: If you are after the Apache's error page then try my solution.

Comment: Any answers for the 400 error page?

Comment: @user1406071 No, you clearly are not understanding my suggestions and you pick whichever seems to work at once. I help people that is willing to learn.

Comment: Explaining clearly how to trigger the error from PHP just as the question asks. Giving four perfectly explained examples that all work. Asker picks the worst answer. LOL