# How to get apache 400 (bad Request) & 401 (authorization Required)?

Tags: php, apache

I'd like to reproduce 400 (bad Request) & 401 (authorization Required)  errors. Can someone please tell me how can I do make them on my server?

Comment: Nothing actually I' just want to get an error message for them, on my server so I can test something out.

Comment: This question looks extremely similar to your recent post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069344/how-to-produce-500-internal-server-error-in-php    Please clarify your need.  Do you just need the server to return a particular http code  or do you need to simulate a true request which would cause these error codes to be produced "naturally".

Answer (score 1):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 401 Bad Request");
```

as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php